Why is `automark` not working as expected?
Okay, so I thought automark is like \automark{section level for \righttmark}{section level for \leftmark}. But automark is not working in some specific cases like this one, where it should have shown section in the even-numbered pages and chapter in the odd-numbered pages.
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\automark[chapter]{section} % Set rightmark to chapters and leftmark to sections

\lehead{\leftmark} % Left side of header
\rohead{\rightmark} % Right side of header

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}




Note: This is a bug. It is changed for the next release. But currently you need to use l3build to install the developer version and get a fixed version of scrlayer.

The bug has been fixed and an update is available on CTAN. The problem cannot be reproduced using an up-to-date version. So I vote to close this question.

It's not absolutely clear, what you want, but IMHO either:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% same like \automark[section]{chapter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lehead{\rightmark} % Left side of even page header
\rohead{\leftmark} % Right side of odd page header
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Other Section}
\lipsum[6]
\section{Another Section}
\lipsum[7-40]

\end{document}


\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lehead{\rightbotmark} % Left side of even page header
\rohead{\leftmark} % Right side of odd page header
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Other Section}
\lipsum[6]
\section{Another Section}
\lipsum[7-40]

\end{document}


The difference is which section heading is used for the header on page 2.
To explain your result
Yes, you are right, the description in the KOMA-Script manual is IMHO not complete. If you use the lower level section for the mandatory argument and the higher level chapter for the optional argument, KOMA-Script uses \@mkleft for \chaptermark and \@mkboth with an empty left argument and a non-empty right argument for \sectionmark. This is a very special case and IMHO it is recommended to always use the higher level as mandatory argument. From the KOMA-Script manual:

Normally, the higher level should be used for the left mark and the lower level for the right mark. This is only a convention and not a requirement, but it makes sense.

But maybe the implementation of this case is a bug and the following would be the correct implementation:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\automark@both}[2]{%
  \ifscrlayer@level@prepared{#1}{%
    \ifscrlayer@level@prepared{#2}{%
      \ifnum \numexpr \csname #1numdepth\endcsname +0\relax
           > \numexpr \csname #2numdepth\endcsname +0\relax
          \automark@leftlow{#2}%
          \automark@righthigh{#1}%
      \else \ifnum \numexpr \csname #1numdepth\endcsname +0\relax
                 = \numexpr \csname #2numdepth\endcsname +0\relax
          \expandafter\def\csname #2mark\endcsname##1{%
            \@mkdouble{%
              \ifnum \c@secnumdepth<\numexpr
                \csname #2numdepth\endcsname +0\relax
              \else
                \if@mainmatter \MakeMarkcase{\csname #2markformat\endcsname}\fi
              \fi
              \MakeMarkcase{##1}%
            }%
          }%
        \else % NOTE: Switched #1 and #2 in this case.
          \expandafter\def\csname #2mark\endcsname##1{%
            \begingroup
              \@tempswafalse
              \if@twoside\@tempswatrue
              \else\ifscrlayer@autooneside\else\@tempswatrue\fi\fi
            \expandafter\endgroup
            \if@tempswa
              \@mkleft{%
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth
                     < \numexpr\csname #2numdepth\endcsname +0\relax
                \else
                  \if@mainmatter \MakeMarkcase{\csname #2markformat\endcsname}\fi
                \fi
                \MakeMarkcase{##1}%
              }%
            \fi
          }%
          \expandafter\def\csname #1mark\endcsname##1{%
            \@mkboth{}{%
              \ifnum \c@secnumdepth
                   < \numexpr \csname #1numdepth\endcsname +0\relax
              \else
                \if@mainmatter \MakeMarkcase{\csname #1markformat\endcsname}\fi
              \fi
              \MakeMarkcase{##1}%
            }%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
    }{}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother

\automark[chapter]{section}
\ohead{\headmark}% Not needed, but to show \ohead instead of \lehead + \rohead.

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Other Section}
\lipsum[6]
\section{Another Section}
\lipsum[7-40]

\end{document}


IMHO only the KOMA-Script author can decide, whether the documentation is incomplete or the implementation is wrong and should be changed. Therefore, I've reported this as an issue to KOMA-Script. And indeed, the KOMA-Script author fixed it for the next release (should be v3.42).
